# XSL Doctype Issue

Tags: php, javascript, xslt

I'm having issues with an XSL template that is outputting to HTML.  There is a javascript being rendered on the resulting HTML page that requires a strict doctype in order to work across all browsers.

However, I cant get the doctype to show up.

Any thoughts on this?  Would it be possible to insert it dynamically, using javascript or php?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Batfan, you will want to look into the [`doctype-system`](http://zvon.org/xxl/XSLTreference/Output/xslt_output_doctype-system.html) and [`doctype-public`](http://zvon.org/xxl/XSLTreference/Output/xslt_output_doctype-public.html) attributes of the [`output`](http://zvon.org/xxl/XSLTreference/Output/xslt_output.html) element.

Update: Even better, look at this other [StackOverflow Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2676171/doctype-declaration-getting-lost-when-using-xsl/2676841#2676841) about it.

Comment: @Jordan - I tried some things that were very similar to that last night and could not get it to work.  It would either not render the doctype or the generated page would just end up being blank.  I'll look over that post and try again tonight.

Answer (score 0):

May be this answer will help you:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/76583812/3586932

```
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping='yes' >&#x3c;!DOCTYPE html&#x3e;&#xA;</xsl:text>
```