# Setting XSL doctype

Tags: html, internet-explorer, xslt, cross-browser, doctype

I have an issue viewing an application in IE8+... Specifically, in IE9, when opening developer tools, its seems IE7 Standards is set as Document Mode.. Upon viewing source, i think the issue is with my doctype displaying as:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

Looking at my code, here is how my doctype is set:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE xsl:stylesheet [
  <!ENTITY nbsp "&#160;">
]>

<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="html" version="4.01" doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd" indent="yes"/>
```

How can i modify this to `<doctype html>`

Thanks

**UPDATE**:

Looking through the code further, within the:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
```

section, there is no meta settings.

Comment: I may be misreading or forgetting a lot of stuff but it looks like you are using HTML when you should be using XHTML but XHTML does not work in IE<9.

Comment: @Rob - Thanks, i guess what my issue is then, why when opening the application in IE9.. Is the Document Mode set to IE7?

Answer (score 1):

In short, you can't. `<!DOCTYPE html>` is (deliberately by the HTML5 spec) no valid XML doctype (and no valid SGML, too, which HTML 4 was).

The [HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/syntax.html#the-doctype) dictates this doctype, instead:

```
<!DOCTYPE html SYSTEM "about:legacy-compat">
```

You can generate it with this `output`:

```
<xsl:output method="xml" doctype-system="about:legacy-compat"/>
```

However, when the XSLT processor wants to process/validate the system identifier, it will fail. AFAIK, it should work in MSXML.

Comment: thanks for the advice, i guess what my issue is then, why when opening the application in IE9.. Is the Document Mode set to IE7?

Comment: Do you have any `X-UA-Compatible` headers (either in the HTML or the HTTP response)?

Answer (score 0):

I use this code:

```
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping='yes' >&#x3c;!DOCTYPE html&#x3e;&#xA;</xsl:text>
<html>
```

This generates:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
```

I know no other way... :-(