# XSLT variable scope with import

Tags: xml, xslt, scope, include, global-variables

I'm building an incredibly ambitious and almost certainly doomed client-side CMS (using XSLT 1.0, which is supported by most browsers). As part of it, I'd like to have `template.xsl` to be a stylesheet, and have the business logic be included from `config.xsl`.

Here's the sort of XML file I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="/XRCS/xrcs/template.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<xrcs:page id="/"
           xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
           xmlns:xrcs="xrcs:xrcs">
    <xrcs:title>XRCS Home Page</xrcs:title>
    <xrcs:content>
        Hello I am some HTML!
        <p>
            Paragraphs!
        </p>
        <h2>Headings!</h2>
        <p>
            More paragraphs!
        </p>
    </xrcs:content>
</xrcs:page>
```

To start with, I wanted the page title to be customisable from `config.xsl`. I thought that this would be pretty simple:

- `template.xsl` — the actual stylesheet

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                  xmlns:xrcs="xrcs:xrcs"
                  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <xsl:import href="config.xsl" />

      <!-- DOCTYPE from
           https://stackoverflow.com/a/22302701/522375 -->
      <xsl:output method="xml"
                  doctype-system="about:legacy-compat" />
      <xsl:template match="/">
          <html>
              <head>
                  <title><xsl:value-of select="$site-name" /></title>
              </head>
              <body>
                  <h1><xsl:value-of select="/xrcs:page/xrcs:title" /></h1>
                  <xsl:copy-of select="/xrcs:page/xrcs:content/*" />
              </body>
          </html>
      </xsl:template>
  </xsl:stylesheet>
  ```
- `config.xsl`

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                  xmlns:xrcs="xrcs:xrcs"
                  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <!-- Global variables -->
      <xsl:variable name="site-name" select="'XRCS'" />
      <xsl:variable name="xrcs-url" select="'/XRCS/xrcs'" />

      <!-- Extensions -->
      <xsl:import href="extensions/core.xsl" />
      <xsl:import href="extensions/include.xsl" />
      <xsl:import href="extensions/citations.xsl" />
  </xsl:stylesheet>
  ```
- `extensions/*` are all just an empty `<xsl:stylesheet>` element.

Of course, I now know that `$xrcs-url` is almost useless, since imports are evaluated before variables. However, Firefox complains with some unspecified error when attempting to use this stylesheet.

*This stylesheet* (where I've replaced the import with a variable definition), on the other hand, works fine:

- `template.xsl` — the actual stylesheet

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                  xmlns:xrcs="xrcs:xrcs"
                  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <xsl:variable name="site-name" select="'XRCS'" />

      <!-- DOCTYPE from
           https://stackoverflow.com/a/22302701/522375 -->
      <xsl:output method="xml"
                  doctype-system="about:legacy-compat" />
      <xsl:template match="/">
          <html>
              <head>
                  <title><xsl:value-of select="$site-name" /></title>
              </head>
              <body>
                  <h1><xsl:value-of select="/xrcs:page/xrcs:title" /></h1>
                  <xsl:copy-of select="/xrcs:page/xrcs:content/*" />
              </body>
          </html>
      </xsl:template>
  </xsl:stylesheet>
  ```

Why?!

The only explanation I've come up with so far is that the variables are file-specific. If that's the case, I shall be very, very annoyed, but I suppose I could define *yet another schema* for a configuration to live in, and use that `$xrcs-url` variable after all...

Is my assumption correct? Are these variables file-specific? I've found no documentation on it, and the XSLT spec is a W3 spec (difficult to read unless you already have a very good understanding of it already) so there's no help there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scope of global (top-level) variables, as well as other named declarations such as named templates, is the whole stylesheet, that is, all modules. When module A imports module B, then both modules can declare a variable V, and the declaration of V in A is used everywhere, including in B (in the language of the spec, A has higher import precedence).

If you're trying to write something ambitious in XSLT then I would recommend persevering with understanding the spec. Or you might prefer my book *XSLT Programmers Reference* from Wrox/Wiley - but it covers XSLT 2.0 rather than 1.0, unless you can find an older edition.

I'm having trouble understanding what you mean by "Of course, I now know that $xrcs-url is almost useless, since imports are evaluated before variables."
Imports are not "evaluated", they are declarations used to construct the stylesheet at compile time. I don't know what you want to use $xrcs-url for (your code appears to make no attempt to use it), it seems perfectly usable in principle, though perhaps not what you intended it for (but I don't know what you intended it for, of course).

Incidentally there is one stylesheet here with two modules: it helps to get the terminology right.

Then you say: "However, Firefox complains with some unspecified error when attempting to use this stylesheet." Well, it's probably complaining that the xsl:import declarations are in the wrong place. But more to the point, running XSLT code in the browser is not a good approach for development and testing. The diagnostics are lousy. It's much more productive (you say you're being ambitious) to use a specialized IDE such as oXygen.

Comment: You might want to elaborate on that last paragraph. :-)

Answer (score 0):

`<xsl:import />` has to occur before any other child element of `<xsl:stylesheet />`. That was the direct cause of the error I was getting.

I'm accepting Michael Kay's answer because it actually says this, even though I missed it and have spent a few days trying to figure it out myself!