# Dynamic doctype in XSLT transform (correct use of result-document instruction)

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I'm using XSLT and need to generate the  doctype dynamically in the transformed output, based on a parameter.
I hear that this cann't be done using XSLT 1.0, but can with version 2.0, using the ***result-document*** tag.

So far, from following the answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2676171/doctype-declaration-getting-lost-when-using-xsl) question, I have something like this:

```
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:param name="doctype.system" select="'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd'" />
    <xsl:param name="doctype.public" select="'-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN'" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:result-document doctype-public="{$doctype.public}" doctype-system="{$doctype.system}" method="html">
       <html>
          <head>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="report/head/node()"/>
          </head>
          <body>
             <!-- ommitted for brevity -->
          </body>
       </html>
    </xsl:result-document>
    </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

The problem with the above is no output is generated!

If I remove the results-document tags from the above, my transform is applied and a document is output, as expected.

Any clues? Am I using the result-document tag correctly?

---

**UPDATE**: In response to some of the comments here's a small version that works, and one that doesn't (omitting the parameterisation of the result-document instruction)

This works (no result-document):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/> 
<xsl:template match="/">
   <html>
      <head>

      </head>
      <body>

   </body>
   </html>   
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<html>
<head>
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

But this produces no output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/> 
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:result-document doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd" method="html">
   <html>
      <head>

      </head>
      <body>

   </body>
   </html>
</xsl:result-document>   
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: What is your XSLT processor? XSLT version? And what means "no output is generated? The doctype is not in the result document? The result document is empty? Or no result document is generated at all? `xsl:result-document` is XSLT 2.0 so make sure your engine supports that, otherwise your stylesheet won't compile.

Comment: (Processor: xalan) (XSLT version: this is in the stylesheet header above no? 2.0) (No output = nothing is generated at all)

Comment: You've got an extra `</head>` closing tag in there -- can you post the smallest example that actually works and reproduces your problem, please?

Comment: Incidentally, once I remove the extraneous closing tag, your code seems to work fine for me under Saxon; passing in parameters of "hello" and "test", I get: `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "test" "hello">`.

Comment: @Matt - thanks for pointing that out, I've posted an update to the question.

Comment: @Matt - I wonder if it's a xalan issue then? If I set the XSLT version to 1.0 I get warnings about the result-document tag not being valid wherever I put it. As I didn't get any such warnings with 2.0 I assumed it was supported.

Comment: @Joel I don't know much about Xalan, but everything I just quickly [read](http://xalan.apache.org/) about it seems to suggest it's an XSLT 1.0 processor. Can it even handle XSLT 2.0 documents?

Comment: @Joel: Xalan only supports XSLT 1.0 afaik, so you're out of luck using `xsl:result-document` if you don't change to a XSLT 2.0 compliant processor.

Comment: @Matt, @Per - I'll try swapping out to another version and will report back my findings.

Comment: @Joel Cool. If it helps, I find [Saxon](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/) to be a good processor.

Comment: @Matt, @Pier - You were right, using "net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl" worked a treat. If you guys want to post answers I'll upvote and mark one right.

Comment: @Joel - Happy to leave this one to @Per; his comment is a better answer as it stands, I think.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you also found out, Xalan only supports XSLT 1.0, but if you've changed to Saxon 9, you could easily achive what you want.

Also, instead of defining parameters with your doctype settings, you could define a `xsl:output` with a name and use as a format in `xsl:result-document`:

```
<xsl:output name="my-xhtml-output" method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"
  doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
  doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"/>
```

In your `xsl:result-document` you then use this output format:

```
<xsl:result-document href="{$filename}" format="my-xhtml-output">
  ...
</xsl:result-document>
```

Imo, this makes it easier to maintain different output formats if you have lots of them.

Answer (score 3):

As you are using an XSLT 1.0 engine you will have to create the dynamic DOCTYPE using `xsl:text`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:param name="doctype.system" select="'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd'" />
  <xsl:param name="doctype.public" select="'-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN'" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:text disable-output-escaping='yes'>&lt;!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="$doctype.public" />
      <xsl:text disable-output-escaping='yes'>" "</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="$doctype.system" />
      <xsl:text disable-output-escaping='yes'>"></xsl:text>

      <!-- further processing here -->
      <html>

      </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, as per the comments in the question, an alternative solution suggested was to ensure that I was using an XSLT 2.0 compliant engine. I changed to using Saxon and it works fine. +1 anyway though.