# Adding Doctype instruction to a XML node in XQuery

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xquery

In my XQuery,I have an xml node stored in a variable $d, like:

```
<topic id="IL27TRM409WedNov1919274820081">
<title>Access Switch Failure</title>
<body>
    and Reacting</i> feature of the <i>SMSC User Guide</i>.</p>
</body>
</topic>
```

My question is now, since I need to add three processing instructions including the DocType declaration on the top of the above document, currently the result document is just a pure XML node. So basically I want to add the following three lines:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?exist-serialize indent="no" output-doctype="yes"?>
<!DOCTYPE task PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DITA Task//EN" "task.dtd">
```

at the top. I tried using `concat()` to the `$d`, but failed. I wonder if this kind of explicit XML content manipulation is feasible in XQuery, otherwise I think I have to make change to my XSLT to have `$d` borned-with processing-instructions.

Comment: Your first line is an XML declaration, the second is a processing instruction, the third is a DOCTYPE declaration. Only one of the three is a processing instruction.

Comment: @Michael: Does that suggest the first and third line can be put in more directly?

Comment: No, on the contrary. XQuery 1.0 has syntax for generating processing instructions. It does not have syntax for generating XML declarations or DOCTYPE declarations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To output the XML declaration and the DOCTYPE declaration, you need to set parameters affecting the way the result of the query is serialized. The way you do this depends on the XQuery processor you are using.

To output the processing instruction, use a literal processing instruction in the query body.

Answer (score 1):

You should use processing instructions along with xsl output, something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no" 
    doctype-public="-//OASIS//DTD DITA Task//EN" 
    doctype-system="task.dtd"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:processing-instruction name="exist-serialize">indent="no" output-doctype="yes"
        </xsl:processing-instruction>

        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>
    [...]
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: that helped a bit. But since I have two kinds of templates match, the other one is match with Topic, then the doctype-system should be "topic.dtd", so I can not make it a global "task.dtd", do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I don't really understand... you'd like this xslt to work on xmls with different root tags, and behave differently based on those tags?

Comment: you might want to take a look at [this post](http://www.scriptorium.com/2009/12/2469/) about adding different DTDs to output xmls based on the root node.

Comment: If the question is about dynamic DOCTYPE generation this is a proper link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4275304/dynamic-doctype-in-xslt-transform-correct-use-of-result-document-instruction

Comment: Unfortunately i couldn't get that work in xsl2, but i still keep looking what i might doing wrong there.